# Proof: $f$ square-integrable $\Rightarrow f$ absolutely integrable on $[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series

In a [book](http://books.google.de/books?id=_amjAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=square%20integrable%20absolutely%20integrable%20fourier&source=bl&ots=_2DEn7cwp9&sig=LSRayPlQxS6oqj5KkE-Fs-pPhaU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lkVKVN__FKKfygPhooGgAQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=square%20integrable%20absolutely%20integrable%20fourier&f=false) I found the following statement:

> Let $\varphi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ be square integrable, then $|\varphi \psi| \leq \frac{1}{2} |\varphi^2 + \psi^2|$. This implies, that every square integrabe function is absolutely integrable. To see this, let $\psi(x) = 1$

Now, I tried to proof the second sentence, and I'm not really sure that I did it correct.

Let $\varphi \in L_{2 \pi}^2$. Then we know that

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |\varphi(x)|^2 dx < \infty
\end{align}

Let $\psi(x) = 1$, then (by the inequality mentioned above)

$$|\varphi| \leq \frac{1}{2} (\varphi^2 + 1) $$

Thus

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |\varphi(x)|dx \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} (\varphi(x)^2 + 1) dx= \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \varphi(x)^2dx + \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} dx < \infty$$

Is this correct? Thank you!

P.S. where does $|\varphi \psi| \leq 0.5 | \varphi^2 + \psi^2|$ come from?

Comment: Yes, okay. Re P.S., you can use the AM-GM inequality or $(\lvert\varphi\rvert -\lvert\psi\rvert)^2 \geqslant 0$.

Comment: Thank you @DanielFischer :)

Comment: hi, did you understand where that inequality came from? :(

Comment: @Surferonthefall, what inequality?

Comment: @TheWaveLad $|\varphi \psi| \leq \frac{1}{2} |\varphi^2 + \psi^2|$

Comment: @Surferonthefall This follows from $(|\varphi| - |\psi|)^2 \geq 0$. If you multiply this out and put the $2|\varphi \psi|$ term on the right side and divide by $2$.